# Using JSON.stringify but SSJS variant in XPages

Tags: json, xpages, ssjs

for an application I am building an administration panel where a power user should be able to check the JSON structure of a selected object.

I would like to display the JSON object in a computed text field but display/format it nicely so it is better human readable, something similar as in pretty print.

Is there any function I could use in SSJS that results in something similar so I can use display json nicely in computed text / editable fields?

Answer (score 2):

Use stringify's third parameter ["space"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify(yourObject, null, '  ');
```

> **space**
>   A String or Number object that's used to insert white
>   space into the output JSON string for readability purposes. If this is
>   a Number, it indicates the number of space characters to use as white
>   space; this number is capped at 10 if it's larger than that. Values
>   less than 1 indicate that no space should be used. If this is a
>   String, the string (or the first 10 characters of the string, if it's
>   longer than that) is used as white space. If this parameter is not
>   provided (or is null), no white space is used.

As XPages doesn't support JSON.stringify yet you can include [JSON's definition](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) as SSJS resource and [use it](https://xomino.com/2013/12/18/safe-json-parsing-in-xpages-ssjs/).

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);

Answer (score 2):

As Knut points out, you can certainly add `json2.js` to XPages; I've previously used an implementation [as Marky Roden's post outlines](https://xomino.com/2013/12/18/safe-json-parsing-in-xpages-ssjs/). This is probably the "safest" way of doing so, from the SSJS side of things.

It does ignore the [included `fromJson` and `toJson` SSJS methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323011409/http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_ServerSide_JavaScript) provided out of the box in XPages. While imperfect, they are functional, especially with [the inclusion of Tommy Valand's fix snippet](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/10/xpages-bug-in-fromjson-with-fix.html). Be advised, using Tommy's fix does wrap responses to ensure a proper JS object can be parsed by shoving an Array into an object with a `values` property for the array; so no direct pulling of an Array only.

Additionally, I believe it would be useful to point out that a bean, providing a convenience method or two as wrappers to use either the `com.ibm.commons.util.io.json` methods to abstract the conversion method, or switching in something like [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), might be more powerful and unified, based on your style of development.

Comment: I need it for display purposes only here (just display the content of the json object) . when working with json I use the com.ibm.commons.util.io.json library

Comment: If all you're doing is creating a stringified version of things, `toJson(myVar)` should be the simplest in SSJS; at least as far as what comes with XPages.

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me today!

Answer (score 0):

Knut, Eric, I came so far myself already.

```
function prettyPrint(id) {
    var ugly = dojo.byId(id).value;
    var obj = $.parseJSON( "[" + ugly + "]" );
    var pretty = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);    
    dojo.byId(id).innerHTML = pretty;
}
```

and I call it e.g.

```
var name = x$('#{id:input-currentObjectCollectionFiltered}').attr("name");
prettyPrint(name);
```

I tried to make use the x$ function but was not able to make the ID dynamic there e.g.

```
var ugly = x$('#{id:" + id + "}').val();
```

not sure why. would be nicer if I just would call prettyPrint('input-currentObjectCollectionFiltered'); and the function would figure it out.

Instead of dojo.byId(id).value I tried:

```
var ugly=$("#" + id).val();
```

but things returns and undefined object: I thought jquery would be smarter to work with dynamic id's.

anyway stringify works just fine.

Comment: Did you try this: `var ugly = x$('#{id:" + ${javascript:id} + "}').val();` ?

Comment: that does not seem to work for me. I do not think I get handle on the object.